# Why are my numpy arrays randomly converting to int type?

Tags: python, numpy

I've got some python code that I'm using to analyse model outputs but initialised float64 numpy arrays keep getting converted into int-type and I have no idea why. In particular, this type conversion occurs on lines that have nothing at all to do with the converted arrays. For example:

```
delta = np.zeros(dbdy.shape, dtype=np.float64)
b_vec = np.zeros((2,1)).flatten(); h_vec = np.zeros((2,1)).flatten()

# delta = |b|/|h|
for j in range(0, h_stack.shape[0]): ...
```

According to the debugger, **delta** is indeed initialised as a float64-type array, but once line 2 is executed and the debugger enters the loop, **delta** is converted into an int-type array.

The most bizarre thing is that despite Spyder claiming that the array is int-type, it still contains float values. But it's messing everything up, because imshow is refusing to display these arrays, and simply converting back through .astype isn't working.

What is happening?!

Comment: can you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? we should be able to take the code and run it in our systems.

Comment: If I paste that chunk of code into a new script and replace all of the arrays it is dependent on with simple placeholders then everything works fine, so I'm assuming it's some kind of interaction with something. But I don't understand what, because the line that this conversion is occurring on isn't even touching that variable?

Comment: and that is precisely the point. You may want to roll up your sleeves, and start narrowing things down. May also want to read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Often, the attempt to form an MVCE can help you solve a problem itself. If you can't however, give us your best attempt at an MVCE. We cant solve problems that we dont see.

Comment: as an added tip, give us the shortest version of code that DOES produce the problem, so dont rename things.

Comment: I'm afraid that I think I'm going to have to give up, because I've narrowed it down to a very niche module, but I need it so there's not much else I can do.

Comment: If you know where in the module the problem occurs, you can maybe change the module?

Comment: and  if its a module that can be imported from pip, perhaps do share, maybe it helps someone down the line in the future?

Comment: After several more hours of trying to narrow it down I'm still perplexed, the problem seems to go away by removing different parts of code in different combinations so I'm just going to have to find some kind of workaround. I'm afraid it's not a pip module, it's the diagnostic modules from [this model](https://github.com/edoddridge/aronnax). Frustrated at the moment, if I have the energy to have another look tomorrow I shall update this.